# Reader, Writer, Replicator and Admin access in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm currently working on cloudant but would like to make my app CouchDB compatible.

In cloudant, you can give specific access (reader, writer, replicator or admin) to a user on its database. You simply send the user's permissions to `/_security`.

Is there a way to do the same in CouchDB 2.x? If yes, how? I can't find the doc about that.

Answer (score 0):

There's the same API endpoint in CouchDB 2.x. See http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/database/security.html.

You may also want to refer to the documentation about [CouchDB security](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/intro/security.html?highlight=_users)

Comment: Thanks but in the link you referenced, there is no mention of reader, writer,... accesses but only member and admin. It is not clear to me how I can transpose Cloudant accesses into CouchDB's

Comment: The _reader/_writer/_replicator roles pertain to Cloudant's own security model (see https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/authorization.html#authorization) accessed through the `_api/v2/db/$DATABASE/_security` endpoint which is Cloudant-specific.

Comment: Right... this is what I'm trying to achieve with CouchDB. Any way I could reproduce the same behavior?